# React Native Recompose action not triggering reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, recompose

I'm working on setting up a user login screen in React Native using [Recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose), with separate actions and reducer files, but my reducer is never being called. Currently, there is just a login button that triggers a `doUserLogin()` recompose handler:

loginScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withHandlers, compose } from 'recompose';
import { loginUser } from './user/userActions';

const LoginScreen = ({ user, doUserLogin }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
      {user ? <Text>Hi, {user.name}!</Text> : <Text>NOT Logged in!</Text>}
      <Button title="Log In" onPress={doUserLogin} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default compose(
  connect((state, props) => ({
    ...state.user,
  })),
  withHandlers({
    doUserLogin: props =>
      (event) => {
        console.log('LOGIN USER IN HANDLER'); // <-- THIS IS WORKING
        loginUser();
      },
  }),
)(LoginScreen);
```

The `doUserLogin()` handler in turn calls `loginUser()` in my actions file:

userActions.js:

```
import { LOGIN_REQUEST } from './actionTypes';

export const loginUser = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('In action'); // <-- THIS IS WORKING
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });
  };
};
```

So far, so good. However, when I `dispatch()`, my reducer is never called. But the reducer *is* picking up other actions (from navigation, etc.) - it simply isn't receiving the action from `loginUser()` above:

userReducer.js:

```
import { LOGIN_REQUEST } from './actionTypes';

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('In reducer'); <-- ** THIS IS NEVER CALLED **

  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
      });
    case LOGOUT:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default userReducer;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like I was able to figure this out. In a nutshell, in `loginScreen.js` I needed to add `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions, which are passed to `connect`. `withHandlers` can then `dispatch` the `loginUser()` function in my actions file as a prop.

updated **loginScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withHandlers, compose } from 'recompose';
import { loginUser } from './user/userActions';

const LoginScreen = ({ user, doUserLogin }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
      {user ? <Text>Hi, {user.name}!</Text> : <Text>NOT Logged in!</Text>}
      <Button title="Log In" onPress={doUserLogin} />
    </View>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state.user,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loginUser: () => {
    dispatch(loginUser());
  },
});

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withHandlers({
    doUserLogin: props =>
      () => {
        console.log('LOGIN USER IN HANDLER');
        props.loginUser();
      },
  }),
)(LoginScreen);
```

Any additional advice/suggestions would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for this particular case, you can dismiss completely withHandlers helper.

You only need to pass the action creator to the react-redux connect function, in order to bind it to the dispatch function, just as you shown. Even more, check [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) docs. You can access the props of the component, in the 3rd parameter of connect, and further create handlers that depend on props.

In your case it could be something like this

```
    const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
        return Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps, {
          doUserLogin: () => {
            console.log('LOGIN USER IN HANDLER');
            console.log('accessing a prop from the component', ownProps.user);
            dispatchProps.loginUser();
          }
        });
      }
        export default connect(mapStateToProps,
                               mapDispatchToProps,
                               mergeProps)(LoginScreen);
```

Notice how we can create new functions, that will be available as a new prop to the component, in a similar way to withHandler helper

Comment: Hi Jose. Thanks for the answer! Not sure exactly what you're saying though. Can you expand the answer a little, maybe with some code?